# ExcelDna F# and optional arguments

Tags: f#, excel-dna

For scalar (i.e. non array-like) optional arguments, I would use this pattern :

```
[<ExcelFunction(Category= "Test", Description= "Test optional arguments.")>]
let test_test1 ([<ExcelArgument(Description= "Optional. This is a double. Default is 42.0.")>] arg1 : obj) : double = 
    match arg1 with
    | :? ExcelMissing -> 42.0  // the argument was missing
    | :? double as d  -> d     // the argument was a double
    | _               -> -1.0  // otherwise
```

I am not sure if this code is "idiomatic" within Excel-Dna / F# but it seems to "work".

However I am not sure how to proceed for optional array-like arguments. Eg :

```
[<ExcelFunction(Category= "Test", Description= "Test optional arguments.")>]
let test_test2 ([<ExcelArgument(Description= "Optional. This is a double. Default is [42, 42].")>] arg1 : obj[]) : double[] = 
    match arg1.[0] with
    | :? ExcelMissing -> [42.0; 42.0] |> List.toArray // the argument was missing OR it was an empty array
    | :? double as d  -> arg1 |> castToDouble         // the argument was an array and its first argument was a double
    | _               -> Array.empty                  // otherwise
```

The above seems to work for most cases but does not allow to handle the edge-cases properly : eg if arg1 is an empty array. (`castToDouble` being a custom `obj[] -> double[]` conversion function)

What would be the right / idiomatic way to handle *optional* double arrays in F# / Excel-Dna and how could I then rewrite test_test2?

=========== EDIT ===

Following Govert's advice, I tried the following :

```
[<ExcelFunction(Category= "Test", Description= "Test optional arguments.")>]
let test_test3 ([<ExcelArgument(Description= "Optional. This is a double. Default is [42, 42].")>] arg1 : obj) : double[] = 
    match arg1 with
    | :? (double[]) as ds  -> [1.0; 2.0] |> List.toArray   // the argument was a array of double elements
    | :? ExcelMissing      -> [42.0; 42.0] |> List.toArray // the argument was missing OR it was an empty array
    | _                    -> Array.empty                  // otherwise
```

... but unfortunately I get a `#NUM!` output when I pass an array of doubles (or of anything else). It's only when I pass nothing that I correctly get the [42.0, 42.0] array.

Comment: It might be better to declare the type as just 'obj', and then examine from there.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that (please see my Edit section) but without success. What did I get wrong?

Comment: Does "| :? (double[])" ever actually match for you? I would expect that to come to you as an obj array.

Comment: Also, you can't really return Array.empty as a result. There are a couple of problems with that, one obvious, one a bit more subtle. The obvious problem is that you have to give Excel something back that it considers legal to put in a cell (or cells, if you're calling your UDF as an array formula). That means, number (all numbers are actually floating point), string, boolean, or one of the special Excel error values. Excel doesn't know what to do with an empty array. The more subtle issue there is semantics: are you intending to return an error value or a default value in that case?

Comment: @ Jim Foye, `| :? (double[])` does not seem to match. Neither does `| :? (obj[])` but `| :? (obj[,])` does match.

Comment: @ Jim Foye, thanks for highlighting the issue with returning empty arrays. This can make some edge cases tricky to deal with - I had not thought about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This covers all the possibilities:

```
[<ExcelFunction("describes the input argument")>]
let describe(arg1 : obj) : string =
    match arg1 with
        | :? double as d        -> sprintf "Double: %f" d
        | :? string as s        -> "String: " + s
        | :? bool as b          -> sprintf "Boolean: %b" b
        | :? ExcelError as err  -> sprintf "ExcelError: %A" err
        | :? (obj[,]) as arr    -> sprintf "Array[%i, %i]" (Array2D.length1 arr) (Array2D.length2 arr)
        | :? ExcelEmpty         -> "<<Empty>>"
        | :? ExcelMissing       -> "<<Missing>>"
        | _                     -> "!? Unheard of ?!"
```

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that there is no *direct* way to match things like either `obj[]` (1d arrays of obj) or `double[,]` (2d arrays of fundamental types)? That is, in order to match an *optional* *1d* array of *doubles*, I should determine 1) whether it is a missing argument, 2) if not missing, is it a 2d array, 3) if it is a 2d array, is one of its lengths equal to 1 and 4) if it is indeed a 1d array of obj, are all the elements of the same type (eg here are they all double elements)?

Comment: If your parameter is of type `obj` you'll never get a `double[,]` or a 1d `obj[]` from the Excel-DNA marshaling layer. The above snippet shows all the different types you might get. Like the built-in functions, you can return something like `ExcelError.ExcelErrorValue` (#VALUE) if you can't handle a given argument.

Comment: Govert's answer is correct (of course - he is the author of Excel-Dna). So once you know you what you have, and what you have is obj[,], you'll have to do yet more work to see what's in there. You can't assume someone is passing you doubles, for example, there may be other types plus empty cells (which will be ExcelMissing) in there.